# UITableView cells have content hugging and compression resistance properties without constraints?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I'm replicating a custom cell in a `UITableView` that is similar to the default style but I don't see any content hugging and compression resistance properties in the IB inspector until I add constraints to my UI elements. I don't understand why and how can the default cell have content hugging and compression resistance properties even though they do not have any constraints attached to their `UILabel`. Do the default cells have implicit constraints that we can't see?

Edit:

I just added some constraints on my cell elements and removed them immediately and now the inspector shows content hugging and compression resistance properties on my elements magically. Is this a known Xcode bug?

Comment: I would guess that there are default constraints are set in the implementation of the `UITableViewCell`.  Just a guess, but that would make the most sense to me.. Apple wouldn't their own elements to scale poorly considering the increasing number of different screen resolutions they offer.

Comment: @VictorJohnson That was my guess as well, but it just felt strange that those properties would show up in the inspector if they were set programmatically. Thanks for the guess.